# How can I save a previous URL in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a book store and one of the functionalities is that once I am on a page, I would like to filter it more and only show 10 or 20 results per page.

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('show_10') }}">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Show Results
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <button class="dropdown-item" value = "{{ request.path }}" type="button">Show 10 </button>
  </div>
</div>
    </form>
```

So what I want to do is if the current path is a certain route i.e. "/sort_by_rating", then it should go to a function that will only shows results as 10 per page for that search.

```
@app.route('/show_10', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def show_10():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    print(request.data['name'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if "/sort_by_bestseller" in request.form:
            books = Book.query.filter(Book.best_seller == True).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
        if "/sort_by_rating" in request.form:
            books = Book.query.order_by(Book.rating).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
        if "/sort_by_date" in request.form:
            books = Book.query.order_by(Book.date).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
    return render_template('search_by_author.html', books=books)
```

I am very new to web development. I am not sure if my logic is correct. However when I click on the button to show 10 results, it just stays on the current page and no changes happen. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your function only shows the result if the request is a post. But you never told your form to actually send a post. You need to do that with the method attribute:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('show_10') }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed that issue however I am still getting the same results. When I click on the button, it does not move to another page.